# VS Code inserting console log statements when I attempt to select all occurrences

Tags: visual-studio-code

Imagine I have a file with the following code:

```cpp
struct Datum
{
    int a = 17;
    int b = 19;
};

Datum data[4];
```

When I highlight `Datum` and use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (to select all occurrences) VS Code inserts a

```js
console.log('%Datum: ', 'color: MidnightBlue; background: Aquamarine;', Datum);
```

statement on the line immediately below where I've clicked.

Have I accidentally changed a setting somewhere?

Edit:

1. Highlighting something and then selecting 'Selection>Highlight All Occurences' in the menu bar works as expected (it places cursors at each of the correct locations).

Comment: Could you post a screenshot from the VSCode before and after the selection?

Comment: My post describes the before & after state exactly. I have a normal editor session, I highlight some piece of text, I press CMD+SHIFT+L and it inserts the `console.log` statement. Nothing else changes.

Comment: Go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts and check which Commands are executed via the `Cmd+Shift+L` shortcut

Comment: Ah yes! "Insert Log Statement" was mapped to the same keybinding! -- Thank you. (Interestingly it says they're both default actions for that keyset, but it never used to insert the log statements).

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and the command _Insert Log Statement_ does not appear to exist. Perhaps, it was created by a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After the comments discussion*

Another command bound to the same keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) was causing the impairment which was the *Insert Log Statement* command.

The keyboard shortcuts can be found on File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts